# Json response download in IE11

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

I am trying to upload a file and return a json response regarding properties(name, size etc) of the file. It works fine in all browsers except IE.

IE tries to download the JSON as a file !

```
        JSONObject outJsonObject = new JSONObject();
        outJsonObject.put("info", outJsonArr);


        return new ModelAndView(new ListJsonView(),ListJsonView.JSON_ROOT, outJsonObject.toString());
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging or any clues from stack traces ?

Comment: I thick it is somehow related to content type.  But not sure.